# Hiding directory above from being shown in index

Tags: nginx, web-server

I've added an alias to my server. When I go to it, it still shows the "../" that can redirect to the root folder. Can I hide this somehow, specifically in the alias?

```
server {
            autoindex on;
            root /home/myrootdirectory/;

       location / {

       }
       location /specific {
           alias /home/myrootdirectory/specific/;
       }
}
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and there's no point to hiding it. One could simply edit the URL themselves. If you don't want files published on your web server, simply do not publish them.